# Gulp Browserify combine JS

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I am using Browserify with Gulp to handle external Javascript library requirements.

I want to combine all my non-external libraries into one file as well and can't seem to find any documentation on their site about how to do it (and Googling "browserify bundleConfigs" doesn't seem to come up with anything helpful. This is my current configuration:

```
browserify: {
    bundleConfigs: [
        {
            entries: SRC + '/javascript/functions.js',
            dest: DEST + '/js/',
            outputName: 'functions.js',
            require: ['jquery', 'backbone/node_modules/underscore', 'backbone']
        }
    ]
}
```

I also tried:

```
 entries: [ SRC + '/javascript/functions.js', SRC + 'javascript/menu.js' ]
```

But that doesn't seem to work either.
Has anyone else managed to get this working, or is there a different way I am supposed to be doing this?

Thanks

Comment: What is `bundleConfigs`? What file is your current configuration in?

Comment: have been basing it on this: https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter/blob/master/gulp/config.js

Comment: ah it is an arbitrary variable which is used in here: https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter/blob/master/gulp/tasks/browserify.js  that would explain why I couldn't find any docs! thanks for the help, will look into what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out I could do this with:

```
require('./myfile'); //not `./myfile.js`
```

In the base javascript file.